# can any one describe the different jar files on seleniumhq.org

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[Library File](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/)

can anyone explain ob above path , Which zip file is used for which perpose. I have just started with Selenium . Request you to please explain which is used for which purpose. Which is better for beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium Webdriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) is used to automate web applications. There are 2 versions present for each jar, `2.53.0` & `2.53.1` in the given link. I suggest to always pick the latest and stable version (latest being 3.0 version). All implementations of the WebDriver (FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, etc) communicates with the browsers using [JsonWireProtocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).

description of each jar is as follows:

1. `selenium-java-2.53.1.zip`: Client side bindings of WebDriver. used to write scripts that run on a local machine. Provides the Java API. so, if you want to automate a browser using Java in local machine, you should download and put it in the PATH, so your code can access them. In Eclipse, you keep it in `Right click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Add External Jars -> select the jar -> Apply -> Ok`.
2. `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar`: Server side bindings of WebDriver. used to write scripts that run on a remote machine. if you want to automate a browser using Java & run scripts in the remote machine, you should download and put it in the PATH, so your code can access them.
3. `selenium-dotnet-2.53.0.zip`: same as  `selenium-java-2.53.1.zip`, but provides `dotnet api`. Choose this If you want to write the scripts in `dotnet`. similarly, there are language specific bindings available in order to write the scripts. eg: python, ruby, javascript etc. You can choose your own language bindings irrespective of the language used to build the web application.
4. `IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0.zip`: Required to automate Internet explorer browser. It acts as a proxy b/w client side bindings and the actual browser. Note: each browser has its own `.exe` file. for Firefox, it is `geckodriver.exe`, for chrome it is `chromedriver.exe`, for safari it is `SafariDriver`. This zip file is for `64 bit` OSs. there is `32 bit` version also present with the name of `IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0.zip`. so, pick based on the bit version the machine. Also, keep these .exe files in the `System Path` so that they can be picked.
5. `selenium-server-2.53.0.zip`: used to run the scripts in a grid. i.e., run your scripts in multiple machines in parallel.

---

Suppose you want to start with writing scripts using Java for chrome browser, you need following jars:`selenium-java-2.53.1.zip` & `chromedriver.exe`

example code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class SeleniumExample{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Python27\\chromedriver.exe"); // you can also keep the .exe file in System Path to avoid this line.
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//launches chrome browser
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Note: once you write the scripts, same scripts can be run on different browsers by creating an object of that browser WebDriver implementation and **rest of the code remains same**.

Lets say, now you want to run scripts on Firefox,

example code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class SeleniumExample{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Python27\\geckodriver.exe"); // you can also keep the .exe file in System Path to avoid this line.
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // only this line changes, launches firefox browser
            driver.get("http://www.google.com"); //remaining code is same
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

References:

1. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/
3. https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/
4. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Now i'm pretty clear on this ,